# Movie about a museum with a painting that became a portal when struck by lightning

Tags: story-identification

Very happy to have found this site, as someone here might have the answer to a question that has been bothering me for years. It would be great to find out whether this film was real or just a dream!

I remember seeing a movie when I was very young that may have been released exclusively for TV, probably sometime in the 1990s or even early 2000s. A family was visiting a museum, and a bolt of lightning struck one of the paintings, turning it into a portal. One of the museum visitors was instantly transported into the painting, and one of the subjects in the painting was sent into our world in exchange. The painting was a medieval scene. I recall one of the characters in the film as a bumbling knight, and in the family visiting the museum, there was at least one daughter and a father. They had to wait for another bolt of lightning to return their family member to the real world.

That is all I remember of the movie. It has been rather frustrating, as I do not recall the explanation they gave for the painting becoming a portal, or what became of the family.

Thank you in advance! Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sound like [night at the magic museum](https://books.google.com/books?id=ajp2CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA405&lpg=PA405&dq=painting%20portal%20movie%20lightning&source=bl&ots=gYKDnVNM1o&sig=YrI9XoMbv9uEMrTnt0RhSIWWqsU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAWoVChMIyoaNldabxwIVRhuSCh2T7gd1#v=onepage&q=painting%20portal%20movie%20lightning&f=false) or [mysterious museum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGTyPtpxtro). (I think they are the same movie but not sure.)

Comment: Those are the same movie, yes. [Magic museum 6:19](https://youtu.be/azc4ZTIDdwM?t=6m19s) vs [Mysterious museum 0:20](https://youtu.be/NGTyPtpxtro?t=20s)

Comment: Oh my goodness, that's it!! I didn't dream the movie into existence after all! Thank you so much!